# How to delete data with 2 primary keys in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

my route in web.php

```
    Route::post('delete_master_cuti', [CompanyMasterCutiController::class, 'delete_master_cuti'])->name('delete_master_cuti');
```

my model in App\Models, I've added the company_id and year to be for the primary key

```
class CompanyMasterCuti extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'company_master_cuti';
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'year', 'cuti', 'created', 'created_by', 'modified', 'modified_by', 
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = ['company_id', 'year'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

my code in controller

```
    public function delete_master_cuti(Request $request) {

        $master_cuti = CompanyMasterCuti::where($request->company_id)->where($request->year);
        $master_cuti->delete();

        toast('Successfull', 'success');
        return redirect()->route('master-cuti.index');

    }
```

[image]
index.blade.php, in this code i just added company_id, i also don't know how to call year.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="{{ $m_cuti->company_id }}"                                                               onclick="$('#master_cuti_ids').val($(this).data('company_id')); $('#deleteModalBu').modal('show');">
     <i class="badge-circle badge-circle-light-secondary bx bxs-trash font-medium-1 text-danger my-1"></i>
 </a>
```

form action to delete function delete data in index.blade.php

```
 <form id="form-edit" action="{{ route('delete_master_cuti') }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" id="master_cuti_ids" name="company_id">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
 
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ml-1" style="width: 100%">
                                        <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Delete</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I want to delete data based on company_id and year but for now all the same company_id is deleted, I want the data to be deleted according to what the user chooses, not all company_ids. is there any solution for my problem?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know Laravel does not support a composite primary key. I think it's best if you create an autoincrementing field and set that as the primary key. You also are missing the `year` in your form

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround and you should override the Model method

```
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery($query)
    {
        $query
            ->where('company_id', '=', $this->getAttribute('company_id'))
            ->where('year', '=', $this->getAttribute('year'));

        return $query;
    }
```

After reading a lot I found this
https://blog.maqe.com/solved-eloquent-doesnt-support-composite-primary-keys-62b740120f

This worked for me to delete a record with 2 primary keys like you.